# react-easy-state - one store triggering change in other with debounce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-easy-state

I'm trying to solve the following pattern using the react-easy-state library: I have two stores containing one string for example:

```
filter = store({
    search : ""
})

backendFilter = store({
   search : ""
})
```

I would like that when I call a change to the search in filter it changes the value in backend filter but debounced.

My idea was :

```
filter = store({
   search : "",
   setFilter(value) {
      filter.search=value;
      backendFilter.setBackendSearchString(value);
   })
}

backendFilter = store({
   search : "",
   setBackendSearchString(string) {
        debounce(
            () => {
                backendFilter.search = string;
            },
            600,
            true
        )();
   },
})
```

But this is unfortunately not working, just delaying the change but when I use an onChange handler on an input to trigger filter.setFilter the backendFilter is changing as many time as filter just with a little delay. I know in a React component the problem is generally to use useCallback as you have to make sure the function you call in denounce is always the same but couldn't find a solution to have it work there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `debounce(() => {...})()` you are basically creating a new function every time you call `setBackendSearchString`.

I would instead wrap `setBackendSearchString` in debounce:

```
backendFilter = store({
  search: "",
  setBackendSearchString: debounce(
    (string) => {
      backendFilter.search = string;
    },
    600,
    true
  ),
});
```

Al alternative would be to make/use a hook which creates a debounced value for you, like this one: https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce

Answer (score 1):

tudor.gergely's answer is correct, I only have some easy-state specific extra thoughts.

You can use an `autoEffect` to create a "hook like" auto-derivation for your use case.

```js
import { store, autoEffect } from "@risingstack/react-easy-state";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

export const frontend = store({
  search: "",
  setSearch: ev => (frontend.search = ev.target.value)
});

export const backend = store({
  search: frontend.search,
  setSearch: debounce(search => (backend.search = search), 600)
});

autoEffect(() => backend.setSearch(frontend.search));
```

Related codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-http-jsfyd?file=/src/stores.js:0-390

This way any time you set `frontend.search` `backend.search` will also get updated with a debounce. Be careful with this though. `autoEffect` is mainly intended for end-of-chain effects (like rendering), if you use it too much for deriving data from data you will quickly get lost in complex automatic data flows. (This is one of my issues with vanilla React hooks).